# Fontawesome style: Solid, regular, light

Tags: fontawesome

Is it possible to specify the style for font awesome:?
For example, \faAlignJustify has three different styles:

https://origin.fontawesome.com/icons/align-justify?style=light

https://origin.fontawesome.com/icons/align-justify?style=regular

https://origin.fontawesome.com/icons/align-justify?style=solid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fontawesome5` package offers the possibility to specify `solid` or `regular` as an optional argument, `solid` is the default:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

  \faFile

  \faFile*

  \faFile[regular]

  \faFile*[regular]

  \faFile[solid]

  \faFile*[solid]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

According to the documentation, the `light` style is also available in the with the pro version of the package (only compatible with xelatex or lualatex)

Comment: Thank you. It seems I was using an older fontawesome version. Actually am having some issues trying to install it in my debian.

Comment: @Rod If you ditch the texlive version from debian and install the one available from tug.org you will the newest version of all packages

Comment: I'm migrating my container to Debian sid, it seems it includes the newest versions. If I could not get it to work easily, certainly, I will use your approach and get the newest from tug.org Again, many thanks.